# Codeigniter: Count columns with value for user

Tags: codeigniter, count

How do I get a count of columns where('user_id', $id)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Row Counts**

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->from('myTable');
$cnt = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

For more details please see the CodeIgniter Documentation on ActiveRecord

[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

**For Colunm Counts**

```
$query = $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->get('myTable');
$cnt = $query->num_fields();
```

For more details please see the CodeIgniter Documentation on Database Query Results

[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Oh you're right... bonk on my head for not reading the question! Updated with column counts.