# Codeigniter: Count columns not NULL for user

Tags: codeigniter

I just asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791897/codeigniter-count-columns-with-value-for-user) question, but failed to specify that I would like to get the number of fields that actually have a value.  I need to know how many fields have something in them, so I can get a percentage of filled out fields per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $data['member'] = $this->model->getUser($id); 

    $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->get('user_profiles');
    $data['results'] = count((array) $query);
```